# Creating a Dictionary of Dataframes from a Large Dataframe based on Multi-Index via a Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if this seems simple but have been struggling to find an answer to this.

I have a large dataframe of the format in the picture:[image: dataframe]

Each row can be uniquely identified by the multi-index built from the columns "trip_id", "direction_id", "stop_sequence".

I would like to request methods using loops to create a python-dictionary of dataframes where each dataframe is a subset of the large dataframe which contains all the rows for each "trip_id" + "direction_id" multi-index.

At the end of the loops I would like to be able to have a python-dictionary of dataframes where I can access each dictionary with a simple index key such as from 0 - 10,000 or the key being the combination of trip_id and direction_id

E.g. for the image above, I would like all the rows where the trip_id is "17067064.T0.2-EPP-F-mjp-1.8.R" and the direction ID is "1" to be in one dataframe of this dictionary collection.

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards,

Ben

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry but it's just a table, the code and the files to create the table I felt would have been too much.

Comment: yes, I understand, the best here is create some sample data like `df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,5,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
}).set_index(['F','B','C'])` instead pictures.

Comment: Ah I see thanks again Jezrael, I appreciate your advice and help

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `dictionary comprehension`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,5,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
}).set_index(['F','B','C'])

print (df)
       A  D  E
F B C         
a 4 7  a  1  5
  5 8  b  3  3
    9  c  5  6
b 5 4  d  7  9
    2  e  1  2
  4 3  f  0  4
       A  D  E
```

---

```
#python 3.6+ 
dfs = {f'{a}_{b}':v for (a, b), v in df.groupby(level=['F','B'])}
#python bellow
#dfs = {'{}_{}'.format(a,b):v for (a, b), v in df.groupby(level=['F','B'])}
print (dfs)
{'a_4':        A  D  E
F B C         
a 4 7  a  1  5, 'a_5':        A  D  E
F B C         
a 5 8  b  3  3
    9  c  5  6, 'b_4':        A  D  E
F B C         
b 4 3  f  0  4, 'b_5':        A  D  E
F B C         
b 5 4  d  7  9
    2  e  1  2}

print (dfs['a_4'])
       A  D  E
F B C         
a 4 7  a  1  5
```